# Video output is bad quality

Tags: rendering, export, video

Hello while I understand this is a 3d animation software not a video editing software, I have heard of people getting great quality videos with the video editing feature in blender. I watched a few tutorials and researched settings for good video quality but for some reason I cannot get good video output. No matter the render settings I use my video ends up pixelated and terrible looking (source file is great quality).

I am basically trying to render gaming videos at 1080p, 60fps for Youtube I don't know what I am doing wrong but I can't seem to render a good quality video.

The below settings I found on the internet which was recommended for Youtube but quality wasn't very good after my testing
Format = xvid
container = AVI
codac = h.264
bitrate=10000
min-rate 7000
max-rate 15000
Gop-size=15

settings below I configured myself to try get the best but still didn't work
format = H.264
Codac = H.264
bitrate = 10000
min=rate=5000
max-rate=20000
buffer=2000
GOP size=1

Am I doing something wrong? Has anybody got a better render setting that I could try?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: You mentioned terrible looking.  You stated source file is (great quality).   Are you stating that Blender renders great quality video and that after upload to youtube the video that youtube presents to the world is terrible looking?  I think I am reading Blender is good.  Youtube transformation is terrible.  Is that correct?   Is your question How can I make my video more compatible with the requirements of youtube?

Comment: I suggest your side note of CPU and GPU utilization be a separate question.

Comment: I didn't know Blender could edit imported videos.  GIGO (garbage in/garbage out) is the rule.  The question is how did you import it, what format the video; and how did you export it. I'd like to know, what kind of editing you expect to do in Blender?  Blender is 'very' settings sensitive, the usual answer is "Yes, there's a setting for that!" but, my typical thinking is, "But what that setting does, I don't know".

Comment: GOP of 1 is not recommended. It means every frame is an I Frame, there is no temporal compression. Try GOP of 30 or more.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger no i mean the file i recorded before editing in blender looks great but after editing and rendering in blender the file comes out looking terrible

Comment: @Cyberchipz i imported through the file/import option, the imported file is .mp4, i exported through the render/animation in the video editor section. I only need to do simple editing like adding audio, cutting clips and some transitions.

Comment: @mike Pan I understand GOP on 1 is not recommended to be on one but i set it to that to try increase quality by reducing any and all compression to see if that was the problem.

Comment: When I had trouble with the output quality it turned out to be from the "lossless output" at "encoding" that wasn't set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need to go at very high rates in blender. it uses single precision compression. think about doing 1080p60 at the 45-60mpbs range. at 10mbps you will get you lots of artifacts

Comment: Thanks ill try that out i used 10mbps because i believed it was the highest setting never tried to manually input the settings haha

Answer (score 3):

It could be something as simple as setting the output quality from 50% (Default) to 100%

[image]

You didn't explicitly mention this.

Comment: Thanks I have already set that to 100% didnt seem to make much difference but i didnt realize it was output quality either i just changed it saw no difference and forgot about it haha but thanks again because this will help with fine tuning after i find out what my problem is

Comment: Why does it default to 50%?

Comment: @0xcaff , i can only speculate but the first few renders any user will do will almost never need to be full size. You can setup your default .blend to have that value at 100% if you are really confident :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just cycle render to images and place them into davinci resolve. I have spent countless hours watching tutorials and messing with settings to no avail. 2.7b Blender had a different algorithm to produce less grainy videos unlike 2.8 versions.